# How to create a ASP.NET project that will run on Linux Debian - ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, debian

[image]

And I tried contacting support and this is what they said:

Our Administrators have attempted to run your website with a different config and default.aspx files - unfortunately the directory listing still occurred, which could mean that our Mono version is not supporting your current ASP.NET web configuration.

Please note that our servers run under Linux Debian - ASP.NET compatibility is not native and we use a type of emulation for ASP.NET functionality (called Mono).

http://www.monodevelop.com/documentation/creating-aspnet-projects/

If you'd like to run your ASP.NET with no difficulties, we recommend you host it on a Windows-based server.

How would a create a project that would run on this?

Comment: Please try the official docs and Microsoft learn if you want to get started

Answer (score 0):

Just check Asp.net 5 formerly asp.net core. This newest framework allows developers to build apps for windows, linux and mac OS

[Check this](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/aspnet)